# How to insert data to a specific column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a dataGridView with 5 columns in which I enter my rectangle coordinates and with auto indexing. So the index increases with each new coordinate set. Index number is entered in 1st column, coordinate is entered in second. I have an array where i store my coordinates and index numbers, i process an image in the rectangle and want to enter result data in the corresponding third column of the datagridview. E.G if i process rectangle in 4th row, I want to enter the result data in the 3rd column of 4th row.

I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pb1rectincrcam4; i++)
            {


                framecam4.ROI = PB1Rectcam4[i];
                framefullcam4.CopyTo(framecam4);
                Bitmap bitmap2 = framefullcam4.Bitmap;
               
                    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
                tesseract.Init("C:\\Language\\English", "eng", false);
              var wordList = tesseract.DoOCR(bitmap2, Rectangle.Empty);
                foreach (Word word in wordList)
                {
           
                   
                    CvInvoke.cvPutText(resultimg, word.Text,new System.Drawing.Point( PB1Rectcam4[i].X, PB1Rectcam4[i].Y) , ref font, color);
                  
                    listBox1.Items.Add(word.Text.ToString());
                    g.DrawRectangle(PB1Rectpencam4[i], PB1Rectcam4[i]);
                    pictureBox5.Image = resultimg.Bitmap;

                    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
                    dr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    dr.Cells[i].Value = word.Text;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Insert((i),dr);
                 

                }
```

It adds data to the first row always. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Create a model containing two properties, one for the rectangle coordinates, one for the OCR result. Then use databinding to show a BindingList<yourmodel> in datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

We can directly add values to selected columns of selected rows using :

```
dataGridView1[5, (i)].Value = "Data";
```